# Java - How to load an image in a portable way? (ie, not specifying an absolute address?)

Tags: java, image

I'm making an app that will have a window pop up with an image in it. I've looked at tutorials for loading images in Java online, and they all seem to specify the absolute address of the image. That's great until someone run's my app on their machine. So is there a way to load an image robustly? So that it doesn't matter what machine it's on?

Answer (score 1):

Include the image in the JAR file and use ClassLoader.getResource ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you will be creating a JAR file with all your classes and images. You can do something like:

```
BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/background.png"))
```

This will load the image relative to the base of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing the application on someone's machine you can store the root of the directory structure as part of your installation. Then at runtime the image file will be relative to this root.
OR you can make some assumptions about this root directory. e.g. the directory from where teh application is executed.
OR you can make this configurable by user.